# Open dialog from another thread

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently developing a program that will run tests against a Phabrix SX unit. These tests are running in a different thread to prevent the GUI from hanging. I've now encounter a problem with GUI creation in the working thread and I really don't know how to tackle it.

I need to open different kind of dialogs (QMessageBox, QInputDialog etc.) from the separate working thread. For an example, I need to enter a serial number for one of the tests and I wanna do it with a QInputDialog. If I try to create and execute a dialog in the working thread then the program will crash (because it's not running in the GUI thread).

```
  try
  {
      PhTResult result = test->run();
      emit sequenceFinished(sequenceCounter, result);
  }
  catch (PhabrixExceptions::PhEConnectionFailure e)
  {
      QMessageBox messageBox;
      messageBox.setText(e.what());
      messageBox.exec();
  }
```

I wanna be able to create the dialog via the working thread and display it to the user. Is there any way to create GUI in another thread and send it to the main GUI thread?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56182455/how-to-manage-mainwindow-from-qthread-in-qt/56183266#56183266) to an earlier question.

Comment: But what if I wanna assign values to the class that's running in the working thread with a QInputDialog? A signal is a signal and will only send data from the class to the slot, or am I wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. can I send a reference through a signal and edit it in the connected slot?

Comment: @Warcaith Only GUI seems to be a problem, you can call a proper setter in the slot after QInputDialog obtains value, can't you? Maybe, some thread synchronization would be of need, but nevertheless nothing too complex.

Comment: @G.M. is right. You can create UI elements on UI thread only under Qt. Thus, you should use signals and slots (or other preferred way of triggering some action) in order to communicate between worker and UI threads. For instance, under `PhabrixExceptions::PhEConnectionFailure` you can just emit some connection failure signal which would be catched by the UI thread (with the `e.what()` which is probably some message here), and then this thread would create the dialog with message required.